# Reflection on assembly info from other project apart of same solution

Tags: c#, .net

I have the below code to help me track the version of a solution. The problem is the code to get my Assembly version lives in a Utility project. The project I'm trying to track is the web project. With out moving the code to the web project (because it doesn't belong there), how do I  use reflection to interrogate the other project apart of the same solution?

Utilities\Helper.cs

```
namespace MyProject.Classes.Utilities

public class VersionHelper
{
    private static string AssemblyVersion { get; set; }

    public static string GetAssemblyVersion()
    {
        if(AssemblyVersion == null)
        {
            AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute infoVersion = (AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute)Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();

            AssemblyVersion = infoVersion.InformationalVersion;
        }

        return AssemblyVersion;
    }
}
```

MyWebProject\Web\pages\index.cshtml

```
<footer>
    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - @VersionHelper.GetAssemblyVersion()</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code has to live in the utility project since the web project will not honor Assemble reflection.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).